# Segmentation fault with struct array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Trying to calculate the left most point in an Array of Points, the program blows up on me (segmentation fault (core dump) error).

Here's the interface:

```
//points.h
#define MAX_POINTS 100

struct Point {
   char label;
   int x;
   int y;
};

int leftmostPoint(struct Point points[], int numPoints);
```

Here's the `leftmostPoint` implementation:

```
//points.c
//get the point with the smallest x value
int leftmostPoint(struct Point points[], int numPoints) {
   int smallestX = points[0].x; //assume first point is smallest
   int index;
   for (int i = 1; i < numPoints; i++) {
      if (points[i].x < smallestX) {
         smallestX = points[i].x;
         index = i;
      }
   }
   return points[index];
 }
```

Here's where the magic happens:

```
//magic.c
struct Point points[MAX_POINTS];
//build array via standard input (this works, tested by printing the points)
//only 5 points were added in
displayPoint(points[0]); //works
displayPoint(points[4]); //works

struct Point hull;

hull = leftmostPoint(points, numPoints); //this is where the program blows up
```

I am pretty sure it's an issue of sending pointers and not actual copies of the array (curse c!!), my question is where is the issue exactly and how can I go about fixing it?

Comment: Sorry Jonathan, that was a typo when I was writing up the code here in Stack Overflow! My code reflects the appropriate return, leftmostPoint() does indeed return a struct Point

Comment: When you call leftmostPoint, you pass numPoints. Where is that variable defined?

Comment: Sorry, numPoints is defined earlier in the main after I read how many points the user has inputted. In this example, numPoints is 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the original version of the code, your function `leftmostPoint()` was supposed to return an `int` but you return a `struct Point`.  The compiler should be complaining about this.  *(The code has since been updated to return a `struct Point`.)*

The invocation:

```
struct Point hull = leftmostPoint(points, numPoints);
```

indicates the problem is in the declaration of `leftmostPoint()`, which should be returning a `struct Point` instead of an `int`.

So, fix either by:

```
struct Point (leftmostPoint(struct Point points[], int numPoints)
{
    int smallestX = points[0].x; //take the first point in the list and assume it's smallest
    int index = 0;
    for (int i= 1; i < numPoints; i++){
        if (points[i].x < smallestX){
           smallestX = points[i].x;
           index = i;
       }
    }
    return points[index];
}
```

Or by:

```
int leftmostPoint(struct Point points[], int numPoints)
{
    int smallestX = points[0].x; //take the first point in the list and assume its smallest
    int index = 0;
    for (int i= 1; i < numPoints; i++){
        if (points[i].x < smallestX){
           smallestX = points[i].x;
           index = i;
       }
    }
    return index;
}
```

My suspicion is that the version returning the `int` is more useful; you need to know which entry in the array was the left-most, rather than just the value of the entry.

You'll also note that [paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo) set `index` to zero so as to avoid the possibility of returning a "random" value if the first item in the array is the one with the lowest `x` value.

---

Given that you've fixed what should have been compilation problems, the next question should be indeed be:

- What is the value of `numPoints` in the call to the function?

You can always add printing code to a function to check that you're getting correct data:

```
struct Point (leftmostPoint(struct Point points[], int numPoints)
{
    int smallestX = points[0].x; //take the first point in the list and assume it's smallest
    int index = 0;
    assert(numPoints > 0);
    printf("-->> %s: numPoints = %d: index = %d, x = %d\n",
           __func__, numPoints, index, smallestX);
    for (int i= 1; i < numPoints; i++){
        if (points[i].x < smallestX){
            smallestX = points[i].x;
            index = i;
            printf("---- %s: index = %d, x = %d\n", __func__, index, smallestX);
       }
    }
    printf("<<-- %s: index = %d: x = %d\n", __func__, index, points[index].x);
    return points[index];
}
```

Or variants on that theme.

Comment: Jonathan, I've taken the opportunity to init `index` before the loop since it's likely to return a random value if `points[0]` has the smallest x. Feel free to change my wording if it doesn't gel well with your normal prose.

Comment: @paxdiablo: thanks — I incorporated your change (or equivalent) while I was editing (including the comment about initializing index to 0).